# Theta runtime of 2 logarithmic nested for loops

Tags: c++, runtime, big-o

What Theta runtime has the following code?

```
void f(int n)
{
  for(int i=1; i<n; i*=5)
    for(int j=n; j>0; j/=2);
}
```

I came up with this: T(n) = log(n) * (1 + log(n)) = log(n) + log^2(n)  and now I don't know what to put into the Theta notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

log(n) + log^2(n) = Theta(log^2(n)).  You just need to take the dominant term.  To see this, you can write

```
log^2(n) <= log(n) + log^2(n) <= 2*log^2(n)
```

Which is sufficient to prove that T(n) is Theta(log^2(n)).